# Expected value of $\sin(wt)$

Tags: integration, random-variables, expected-value

I am given a function $W = \sin(wt)$

where $w$ is uniformly distributed between $0$ and $2\pi$

When I calculate $E[W]$, I get $\frac{1-cos(2\pi t)}{2\pi t}$

My question is why is there a $t$ in the denominator? It suggests that expected value gets smaller with time, looking at $W$, I can't see it happening.

Side note :
That $t$ in the denominator comes when I integrate $\sin(wt)dw$

Comment: Have you tried drawing the function $t \mapsto {1 -\cos (2 \pi t) \over 2 \pi t}$?

Comment: $\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}\approx 0$ when $x\approx 0$

Comment: @copper.hat yes it decays with t as I explained. I don't understand why it decays in when looking at sin(wt)

Comment: If $t$ is small then $\sin( w t)$ will be small.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm talking about large t values

Comment: Then it should not be a surprise because each $2 \pi$ cycle cancels out.

Comment: @copper.hat Expected value becoming zero periodically is not the surprise, it's the fact that average periodic value gets smaller

Comment: Yes, because more and more of the $\sin$ on the $[0,2 \pi]$ interval cancels out and only a shorter and shorter interval contributes to the net positive.